# Array values being passed as arrays rather than as strings

Tags: php, phpmailer

I feel like there must be something simple I am missing here, but I am new to PHP. I'm trying to use PHPMailer to send emails with attachments, and I've used the example code exactly as described. However, each of the functions in the example code relating to the file uploading (`PHPMailer::mb_pathinfo`, `hash`, `move_uploaded_file`) all throw errors because an array was passed when they expected a string.

From my inexperienced eyes, it *seems* to be that it's the values of the array being passed (eg `$_FILES['files']['name']`). Yet a var_dump reveals it is indeed an array being passed (`array(1) { [0]=> string(12) "Frame 39.png" }`)

I imagine there must be some way to convert that to a string, but at the same time, it's the same code [directly from the PHPMailer examples](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/send_file_upload.phps), so it seems to be working for everyone else without having to do that. What am I missing?

The relevant lines:

```
$ext = PHPMailer::mb_pathinfo($_FILES['files']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
//PHP Warning:  preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in /home1/public_html/PHPMailer/PHPMailer.php on line 4568

$uploadfile = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), hash('sha256', $_FILES['files']['name'])) . '.' . $ext;
//PHP Warning:  hash() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in /home1/public_html/submit.php on line 58

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) { 
[...]
//PHP Warning:  move_uploaded_file() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /home1/public_html/submit.php on line 60
```

Comment: I'm guessing your upload form has more than one element of `type="file"`? Or is perhaps named as an array, like `name="files[]"`?

Comment: Ah!! That was absolutely it, I simplified the php code down to only work with one file while I was figuring it out, but forgot to change the form to only be for one file too. Removing the `[]` from the `name` worked. Thank you!